# Are classes that take an argument with variable type bad architecture

Tags: python, class, architecture

I'm working on a code base that has multiple Python modules that provide specific functionality each having a class. The classes are imported elsewhere in the code and they take a single argument which is a custom `parameters` object that is created from a configuration file.

This works fine in the application, but it's not great for importing the classes on their own to use their functionality elsewhere because you would have to create a `parameters` object for each class even if the particular class has a single parameter.

To simplify I have the idea of checking the type of the single argument:

- if it's a `parameters` object, proceed as already implemented
- if it's a string, instantiate class in a custom way

```
class Ruler:

    def __init__(self, parameters):
        if isinstance(parameters, paramsObject):
            self.config = parameters
        elif isinstance(parameters, str):
            self.length = parameters
```

After this I could handle `ruler = Ruler('30cm')` without needing to create a  parameters object.

The question is: is that good architecture and if there are some principles I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have proposed an anti-pattern solution to an anti-pattern problem.

It is somewhat unhelpful that the existing architecture (over)uses `paramsObject`.  After all, named function parameters are there for a reason and this just obfuscates what `Ruler` really needs in order to instantiate. It isn't much different to having all functions take `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Your proposed solution is a sort-of manual [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), which Python doesn't have because of the type system.  Python has duck typing, which, to paraphrase, says that if it walks like a `paramsObject` and quacks like a `paramsObject` then it is a `paramsObject`.

In other words, the simpler solution would be to work out which values `Ruler` is looking for in `parameters` and adding only those to a new class:

```
class RulerParameter:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

class Ruler:
    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self.config = parameters

    def get_length(self):
      return self.config.length

my_ruler = Ruler(RulerParameter(30))
print(my_ruler.get_length())
```